# Handling all listed exceptions but one with Spring's @ExceptionHandler annotation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am in reference to Spring MVC's [@ExceptionHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html) annotation.

I would like for my @ExceptionHandler-annotated method **to handle all exception but one or two specific exceptions that would be ignored.**

Is this possible with the Spring MVC 3.2? Is there any workaround?

Comment: Do you wish to ignore those exceptions?

Comment: I would redirect the user to a custom error page/view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not add two handler methods like

```
@ExceptionHandler(value={Exception.class})
public ModelAndView all(){
    return new ModelAndView();//return general M&V
}

@ExceptionHandler(value={Ex1.class, Ex2.class})
public ModelAndView special(){
    return new ModelAndView();//return special M&V
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to do that with the @ExceptionHandler annotation.

One approach that should work is for you to provide an implementation of the [HandlerExceptionResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerExceptionResolver.html) interface. In your implementation you could provide the code from your @ExceptionHandler methods and only execute it for the Exceptions that you wish to handle.

I think for Spring MVC to pick-up your custom HandlerExceptionResolver, it will just need to be registered as a bean within your ApplicationContext.

Comment: AFAIK this won't work. The reason being that @ExceptionHandler annotated method takes precedence over the HandlerExceptionResolver. So any exception throw wouldn't be caught by the HandlerExceptionResolver.

Comment: Thanks Rob: we wanted to avoid that actually but I it does work.

Comment: @shazinltc I think registering a custom HandlerExceptionResolver will remove the default HandlerExceptionResolver chain used by Spring MVC. The org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver will be part of this chain, so a custom HandlerExceptionResolver should prevent ExceptionHandler functionality from working.

Comment: but I just tried. It didn't! It works if I remove the @ExceptionHandler annoatated method

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is will help, but this is what I would have done.

```
@ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
public ModelAndView handleException(Throwable throwable){

    if (throwable != null){
        if (throwable instanceof theExceptionYouWantToIgnore){
            return new ModelAndView("customErrorPage");
        }
//else do your normal business logic and set an appropriate error page
    }
    return errorPage;
}
```